# SAS EG Creating multiple worksheet by ODS

Tags: excel, sas, enterprise-guide

There is two summary tables and one bar chart in my SAS EG project. Can I create output xls-file with multiple worksheet where there will be summary tables and bar chart. I know that ods tagset.excelXP is not suitable here. Maybe I should use another ODS?

I try use this code but instead of bar chart i have blank page:

```
ods excel file="/sas/user_data/flags/multiple5.xls" 
 style=pearl
 options( 
  sheet_interval="none"  
  sheet_name="Sheet1"
 );
PROC TABULATE
DATA=SASHELP.APPLIANC   
    ;
        VAR units_2;
    CLASS units_7 / ORDER=UNFORMATTED MISSING;
    TABLE   
        units_7 *(units_2 * Sum={LABEL="Sum"} )
        all = 'Total'  *(units_2 * Sum={LABEL="Sum"} )      ;
    ;
RUN;
ods excel options(sheet_interval='none' sheet_name='Sheet2'); 
PROC TABULATE
DATA=SASHELP.AARFM
    ;
    VAR lineno;
    CLASS key / ORDER=UNFORMATTED MISSING;
    TABLE 
        /* COLUMN Statement */
        key *(lineno * Sum={LABEL="Sum"} )
        all = 'Total'  *(lineno * Sum={LABEL="Sum"} )       ;
    ;
RUN;
ods excel options(sheet_interval='none' sheet_name='Sheet3');
ods graphics / height=400 width=800 noborder;
PROC GCHART DATA=SASHELP.ADSMSG
;
    VBAR 
     MSGID
 /
    CLIPREF
FRAME   TYPE=FREQ
    COUTLINE=BLACK
    RAXIS=AXIS1
    MAXIS=AXIS2
;
RUN; 
ods excel close;
```

Comment: How are you generating these tables/charts? Are they point+click generated or is there a program that you wrote (or generated) that produces them (SAS code)?  Also, what version of SAS (not EG) are you running - 9.4 or earlier (and if you know, what specific update - TS1M0, TS1M1, etc.)?

Comment: @Joe, i try to write sas program and i use PROC TABULATE and PROC GHART statement. Version of SAS is 9.4.

Comment: @Joe, It would be great if i could create multiply worksheet file using point+click, but i suppose that its impossible.

Comment: SAS 9.4, latest release, supports ODS EXCEL which supports both tables and graphs.

Comment: @Reeza, could you help me with sas code?

Comment: http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2014/08/29/experimenting-with-ods-excel-to-create-spreadsheets-from-sas/

Comment: @Reeza, thanks for the example, but I want to create multiple worksheet document, not single-page.

Comment: Process is same as ODS ExcelXp which is well documented. https://support.sas.com/rnd/base/ods/odsmarkup/excelxp_demo.html Also, check comments of first link.

Comment: @Reeza, i try to use ODS EXCEL but i have a blank page instead of bar chart. Could you check my sas code?

Comment: Does the code work outside of ODS Excel? And what version of SAS 9.4, if not the latest ODS Excel is buggy.

Comment: You should also be creating an XLSX file, not xls.

Answer (score 0):

https://communities.sas.com/t5/ODS-and-Base-Reporting/ODS-excel-amp-multiple-sheets/m-p/261953/highlight/true#M15551

```
ods excel file="C:\elever.xlsx";
ods excel options(sheet_name="SkoleElever" sheet_interval="none");
proc print data=sashelp.class;
run;
proc print data=sashelp.class;
 run;
 /* Add dummy table */
 ods excel        options(sheet_interval="table");
 ods exclude all;
 data _null_;
 file print;
 put _all_;
 run;
 ods select all;
 ods excel options(sheet_interval="none");
 proc tabulate data=sashelp.class;
 class age sex;
 table age, sex;
  run;
  proc print data=sashelp.class;
  where age=12;
  run;
  ods EXCEL close;
```